# Method taking a type name as argument used against a collection of type names

Tags: c#, typeof, system.type

When using the operator `typeof` we provide a type name to obtain a `System.Type` instance:

```
System.Type t = typeof(System.Int32)
```

or simply:

```
Type t = typeof(int)
```

---

What is the exact name/nature of the parameter passed to the operator?.

How can I build a collection of such "type names":

```
???[] typeNames = { System.Int32, System.String };
foreach (??? tn in typeNames) aMethod(tn);
```

Comment: Do you want to pass the name of the type as a string or the type as a `System.Type` object?

Comment: @Progman: Neither, I'd like to pass the type name as in `aMethod(int)` but using a variable. From the current answer I understand it's not possible.

Comment: What about generics? This is some other way how to get the type into a method.

Comment: @Progman: I don't see how to use a generic method here (there is no type which `System.Int32` is an instance of. Type "???" in my code doesn't exist).

Comment: Assuming it is possible to pass a "Identifier" somehow to a method, what do you want to do with it inside the method and why can't it solved with generics or `typeof()`? This might sound like a XY problem.

Comment: @Progman: I haven't said I cannot use `typeof()`. It's just I wanted to know if it was possible without it, just learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the exact name/nature of the parameter passed to the operator?.

A type name - not as a string, but literally present in the code.

> How can I build a collection of such "type names"

You can't, but you could use `typeof` multiple times:

```
Type[] types = { typeof(int), typeof(string) };
```

If you're actually interested in the *names*, you can use the `nameof` operator:

```
string[] names = { nameof(Int32), nameof(String) };
```

Comment: "*If you're actually interested in the names*": The goal is actually to call a method taking a "type name" argument in a loop (clarified the question).

Comment: @mins: So you can use either option I've provided, using Type.Name in the first case, or just the string in the second.

Comment: @JonSkeet : I am reading your book C# in Depth, and decided to explore your answers in StackOverFlow too. I am happy and enjoying all of it. You put so much effort and love. Thanks a lot